# Grails Firebase Cloud Messaging Plugin

Tags: android, grails, google-cloud-messaging

I'm looking to port an application server sending downstream Android GCM notifications over to Firebase Cloud Messaging.  I'm currently using the Android GCM plugin for Grails to send downstream messages.

https://grails.org/plugin/android-gcm

I don't see a Grails FCM plugin to send downstream messages.  I'm I missing something or does it not yet exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to move forward by issuing a Http request directly from Grails. I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links, so I wrapped them in code samples, sorry.  Per

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream
```

> Errors in the 500-599 range (such as 500 or 503) indicate that there
>   was an internal error in the FCM connection server while trying to
>   process the request, or that the server is temporarily unavailable
>   (for example, because of timeouts). Sender must retry later, honoring
>   any Retry-After header included in the response. **Application servers
>   must implement exponential back-off**.

so I decided to use Google's Http Java Client which provides exponential back-off

```
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff
```

For a use case example add the dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.22.0'
```

Then implement a simple controller using the HTTP Post Request example

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream


import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpUnsuccessfulResponseHandler;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpContent
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory
import com.google.api.client.util.ExponentialBackOff
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException

class MyPushController {

def push(String token){

        def postJson = [:]

        def data  = [:]
        data['score'] = '5x1'
        data['time'] = '15:10'

        postJson['data'] = data
        postJson['to'] = token

        log.info "postJson: ${postJson}"

        HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport()

        HttpRequest request = transport.createRequestFactory().buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"), new JsonHttpContent(new JacksonFactory(), postJson));

        HttpHeaders reqHeaders = new HttpHeaders()      
        reqHeaders.setAuthorization("key=${grailsApplication.config.android.fcm.api.key}")
        reqHeaders.setAccept("application/json")
        reqHeaders.setContentType("application/json")

        request.setHeaders(reqHeaders)

        request.setUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(new HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(new ExponentialBackOff.Builder()
                .setInitialIntervalMillis(500)
                .setMaxElapsedTimeMillis(900000)
                .setMaxIntervalMillis(6000)
                .setMultiplier(1.5)
                .setRandomizationFactor(0.5)
                .build()
                ))

        try{

            HttpResponse response = request.execute();

        InputStream is = response.getContent()
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = mapper.readValue(sb.toString(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){})

        // Process response JSON per https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#response
        if(responseMap && (responseMap['failure'] != 0 || responseMap['canonical_ids'] != 0)){
            if(responseMap['message_id'] && responseMap['registration_id']){

                log.info "New push token, setting to ${responseMap['registration_id']}"

                // TODO Notify backend that token has changed, i.e. update

                }

            }else{

                def results = responseMap['results']

                if(results){

                    results.each{

                        if(it['error']){

                            if(it['error'] == "NotRegistered"){

                                log.info 'NotRegistered, updating AppToken to null'

                                // TODO Notify backend this token is no longer valid, i.e. delete

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }

        render responseMap as JSON

        }catch(HttpResponseException e){

            log.error "Error: ${e.toString()}"

            render (['SC' : e.getStatusCode(), 'M' : e.getStatusMessage() ]) as JSON

        }

  }

}
```

Be sure to replace ${grailsApplication.config.android.fcm.api.key} with your FCM Server Key.  Your FCM Server Key can be found by logging into the Firebase console:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com
```

Then go to Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING